# How to play background music with MPMusicPlayerController's applicationMusicPlayer in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller

Hello i am trying to play background music with `MPMusicPlayerController's` `applicationMusicPlayer` in iOS.

I have also added `Required background modes` in Plist.

But it doesn't play background music.

How can i play background music with `MPMusicPlayerController`?

Thanks for your reading. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `applicationMusicPlayer` does not support background music. Use `MPMusicPlayerController`'s `iPodMusicPlayer` instead. It shares the state with the built-in iPod player and music will continue to play when your app enters the background.

Answer (score 3):

Bryan is right about applicationMusicPlayer not playing music in background, but there is another solution:

You can use AVAudioPlayer to play either streamed or local(bundle) audio. It even allows you to play multiple audio file at the same time having an AVAudioPlayer instance for each.

Here's the documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html